# Writing from .csv to different tables

Tags: csv, asp-classic

I need a script to get some values from a .csv file and write the rows into a database: my code is as follow and it works very well, but I need the rows inserted in certain tables, depending on some triggers.

```
set objconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objconn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
objconn.ConnectionTimeout = 15 
objconn.CommandTimeout = 30 
objconn.Open ConString

csv_to_read="ordini.csv"
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set act = fso.opentextfile(server.mappath(csv_to_read),1)

dim sline
dim sSeg

Do Until act.AtEndOfStream

sline=act.readline


sline = Replace(sline,"""","") 
sSeg=split(sline,",")

dim strsql

if  sSeg(4) = "1" then

strsql="INSERT INTO tbl_test (id_order, client, code, description, qty, price)"
strsql=strsql & "VALUES('"&sSeg(0)&"', '"&sSeg(1)&"', '"&sSeg(2)&"', '"&sSeg(3)&"', '"&sSeg(4)&"', '"&sSeg(5)&"')"

end if 

objconn.execute strsql

loop
act.close
set act=nothing


objconn.close
set objconn=nothing
```

What I want is inserting the rows in different tables, depending on the client value. So, if the client = 1, I need the result to be inserted in the tbl_test2 table, otherwise everything can go to the regular tbl_test. I know it can't be made, but I really can't get how...

Answer (score 1):

```
if  sSeg(4) = "1" then

    strsql = "INSERT INTO tbl_test2 ......... "

else
   strsql="INSERT INTO tbl_test (id_order, client, code, description, qty, price)"
   strsql=strsql & "VALUES('"&sSeg(0)&"', '"&sSeg(1)&"', '"&sSeg(2)&"', '"&sSeg(3)&"', '"&sSeg(4)&"', '"&sSeg(5)&"')"
end if
```

if that doesnt work try removing quotes for the value like this:

```
 if  sSeg(4) = 1 then
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I knew it was somehow easy. I found another workaround, but your code is smoother and much simpler, so I'll use it.